# Does an object which enters into a magnetic field cause any electric field measurable for an static observer?

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity, maxwell-equations

Assume an observer is located in a magnetic field (both of the observer and object are stationary with respect to each other, and the magnetic field is constant in time). Suppose an object enters into the magnetic field. There are a few questions:

Considering what Maxwell's equations imply, does the entering object measure any electric field?
If the static observer measures any electric field caused by the entering object?
(thanks to @JohnRennie for his explanations)

Comment: You haven't given any parameters about this object. If it doesn't interact with the magnetic field, then the magnetic field stays constant everywhere, and there is no induced $E$ field.

Comment: @BillyKalfus: I've added the moving object to the system to create a relative movement of the magnetic field which can cause an electric field whether the object is there or not.